# Baire Space and Its Equivalent Property

Tags: the-baire-space

> **Lemma** $X$ is a Baire space if and only if given any countable collection $\{U_n\}$ of open sets in $X$, each of which is dense in $X$, their intersection $\cap U_n$ is also dense in X.

A space X is said to be **Baire space** when for given any countable collection of closed sets of X, where each closed set has empty interior in X, their union also has empty interior in X.

I can't prove why the intersection definition become equivalent to the formal Baire space definition. Any hint to prove it?

Comment: Consider complements.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have such a countable collection $U_n$ of dense open subsets of $X$. Consider $C_n = X \setminus U_n$, each of which are closed. Note that $\operatorname{int} C_n = \emptyset$, otherwise $\operatorname{int} C_n$ would be an open neighbourhood that $U_n$ failed to intersect, contradicting density.

By definition of a Baire space, this means that $\operatorname{int}(\bigcap_n C_n) = \emptyset$. Taking complements of both sides,
$$X = X \setminus \emptyset = X \setminus \operatorname{int}\left(\bigcap_n C_n\right) = \operatorname{cl} \bigcup_n \left(X \setminus C_n\right) = \operatorname{cl} \bigcup_n U_n,$$
i.e. $\bigcup_n U_n$ is dense in $X$.

The converse follows in much the same fashion.